# UnPivot and combine rows in the same statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

What I have

```
ID      Question1           Question2           Question3           Question4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123     Successful          Successful          Successful          Successful  
124     Successful          UnSuccessful        NotObserved         Successful  
125     UnSuccessful        UnSuccessful        Successful          Successful
```

What I need to do

```
ID          Question            Answer
-----------------------------------------------
123         Question 1          Successful
123         Question 2,3,4      Successful
124         Question 1          Successful
124         Question 2,3,4      NotObserved
125         Queston 1           Unsuccessful
125         Question 2,3,4      UnSuccessful
```

So I need to convert A table like the one above into the second one. But I also have to combine questions 2,3,4 so that the answers to those three gives me a new answer.

For example if they are all successful than its successful, however if one has the answer `NotObserved`, then that is the answer, and finally if there is an unsuccessful but not a `NotObserved` then it will return `Unsuccessful`.

I know this is wrong but this is kinda what I was trying to do.

```html
            SELECT ID, Question, Answer,

            CASE
            WHEN
                ((CONVERT(VARCHAR, Q2) = 'unsuccessful')
                  OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR, Q3) = 'unsuccessful')
                  OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR, Q2) = 'unsuccessful')
            THEN
                'unsuccessful'
             WHEN
                ((CONVERT(VARCHAR, Q2) = 'successful')
                  OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR, Q3) = 'successful')
                  OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR, Q2) = 'successful')
            THEN
                'unsuccessful'
              WHEN
                ((CONVERT(VARCHAR, Q2) = 'not_observed')
                  OR(CONVERT(VARCHAR, Q3) = 'not_observed_')
                  OR(CONVERT(VARCHAR, Q2) = 'not_observed_')
            THEN
                'not_observed_'
           
            ELSE null
        END AS [CombinedQuestion]        
           
     FROM table   
     UNPIVOT
      (
      Answers
      for Question in ( Question1, CombinedQuestion) 
                  table;
```

Comment: Any specific question or just "give me the code"?

Comment: I already know how to do an unpivot but i'm not sure of the best way to combine the questions?

Comment: it may be worth putting your code and ask for help

Comment: 1) `UNPIVOT` without "combining" 2) do that "concat strings with `FOR XML`" magic 3) replace `", Question"` with `","`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took another look at your question, here is possible solution:

- convert "result" to something numeric to make it possible to sort asc/desc, take min-max as you described

  - not observed - max priority
  - unsuccessfull - second
  - successfull - if all succeded - lowest priority
- invent something like "question groups" to group them automatically in posterior code

these two items will fix your *big case* problem.

like this:

```
DECLARE @QUIZ TABLE(id int, q1 VARCHAR(100), q2 VARCHAR(100), q3 VARCHAR(100), q4 VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @QUIZ(id, q1, q2, q3, q4)
VALUES
(123,     'Successful',          'Successful',          'Successful',          'Successful'), 
(124,     'Successful',          'UnSuccessful',        'NotObserved',         'Successful'),  
(125,     'UnSuccessful',        'UnSuccessful',        'Successful',          'Successful')  

;WITH cteQUIZ AS
(
    SELECT
        z.*,
        CASE z.a
            WHEN 'NotObserved' THEN 0
            WHEN 'UnSuccessful' THEN 1
            WHEN 'Successful' THEN 2
        END as res,
        CASE q
            WHEN 'q1' THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END as group_id
    FROM @QUIZ qz
    UNPIVOT
    (a FOR q in (q1, q2, q3, q4)) z
)
SELECT
    qz.id,
    CASE qz.group_id
        WHEN 0 THEN '1'
        WHEN 1 then '2,3,4'
    END q_group,
    CASE MIN(qz.res)
        WHEN 0 THEN 'PENDING'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'FAIL'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'DONE'
    END result
FROM cteQUIZ qz
GROUP BY qz.id, qz.group_id
ORDER BY id, q_group
```

[image]

I changed `result` names to make my idea more clear. Actually you should not store answer results like `"SUCCESSFULL"`. There should be ids of "flags". Not text.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding.  This is exactly what I need.  However I"m getting an error Msg 402, Level16, State 1 The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.  This is on the line  - END as res

Comment: @JoshPlaetzler add create script of your table into question post.

Comment: I figured out what is wrong my column data is saved as text not varchar.  I'm going to correct this and then give it a try again.  Thanks

Comment: @JoshPlaetzler you better convert it to `tinyint`: 'NotObserved' -> 0, 'UnSuccessful' -> 1, 'Successful' -> 2. And convert it into readable text only when showing to user.